# Filtering by difference in dates in where SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a script that collects data from many different tables, and returns all the results, the script was not written by me and has 1000+ code lines. To simplify:

```
SELECT 
       date_of_opening,
       ...<many other columns>
FROM
       <some other sub queries>;
```

As it returns whole set of data, I thought to limit it, only to those that were opened in certain period of 30 days, I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
      (SELECT 
              date_of_opening,
              ...<many other columns>
       FROM
              <some other sub queries>)
WHERE date_of_opening - to_date('23.01.2011','dd.mm.yyyy') BETWEEN (-30) and (-1) ;
```

Which resulted in

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE.

However if I try the same query in select, it will show the difference as correct one:

```
SELECT 
       date_of_opening,
       date_of_opening - to_date('23.01.2011','dd.mm.yyyy') as difference,
       ...<many other columns>
FROM
       <some other sub queries>;
```

Assuming for example that date_of_opening is `31.12.2010` difference will be `-23`

I have also tried to first calculate difference and then filter it in where as `where difference between (-30) and (-1)` but got

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Datatype of past_of_opening is Date

What method can I use to filter the results, or what is the cause of such behavior?

Comment: Is it possible `date_of_opening` is cast to a different type in the part of the query you have not shown us? Because you query should work: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8532a5937e8f08df5f2b556e40ad7e1d

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't see casting action in the query. Also in select I tried to calculate difference, and it actually succeeded, I have also tried to `to_number(difference) > (-30)` which didn't help at all

Comment: Did you look at the example from my link? The condition you have shown us works. There must be something in the part of the query you have **not** shown us that breaks this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I visited the link, I have also tried it myself before, however I really couldn't find any casting on `date_of_opening`, starting to doubt myself whether I missed something, but rechecked twice by now still don't see any manipulation of `date_of_opening`

Comment: As I said: there must be something in the part you are not showing us that breaks this. Probably an _implicit_ cast that you are not aware of. But as you chose to not show us the complete code this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what about `date_of_opening - to_date('23.01.2011','dd.mm.yyyy') as difference` isn't this something proving that `date_of_opening` is still a date since it is allowing to find period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A period of 30 days might be:

```
WHERE date_of_opening  BETWEEN (to_date('23.01.2011','dd.mm.yyyy')-30) and (to_date('23.01.2011','dd.mm.yyyy'))
```

Assuming that date_of_opening is indeed a DATE.

Comment: works fine, thanks. Any idea on what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: Not sure but I think this way is better readable and, if available, an index on date_of_opening might be used.